# Adding JSON Array to already existing JSON file

Tags: java, json-simple

I have already existing JSON file similiar to this:

```
[{
    "x": []
}]
```

and I want to put prepared JSON Array as a value for "x" key.
How to do it using JSON Simple library?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
    jsonObject.put("x", jsonArrayWithValueForXKey);
    jsonArray.clear();
    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
```